# Use str split but based on position of specials character

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

Hi can anyone help me on this ??

```
C <- "NURUL AMANI [ID 26378] [IC 971035186514] SYED SAHARR [ID 61839] [IC 981627015412]"
str_split(C, "\\]")
```

The result is like this.

```
[1]"NURUL AMANI [ID 26378" " [IC 971035186514" [3]" SYED SAHARR [ID 61839" " [IC 981627015412"
```

I want the result to be like this

```
[1]"NURUL AMANI [ID 26378] [IC 971035186514]" [2]" SYED SAHARR [ID 61839] [IC 981627015412]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base`, you can do this:

```r
strsplit(C,"(?<=\\])(?= \\w)",perl = TRUE)
```

and get with the space before `SYED`:

```r
> strsplit(C,"(?<=\\])(?= \\w)",perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "NURUL AMANI [ID 26378] [IC 971035186514]"  " SYED SAHARR [ID 61839] [IC 981627015412]"
```

If you don't want to keep this space, you can write:

```r
> strsplit(C,"(?<=\\]) (?=\\w)",perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "NURUL AMANI [ID 26378] [IC 971035186514]" "SYED SAHARR [ID 61839] [IC 981627015412]"
```

Comment: FYI: It is safer to use `perl = TRUE` as `T` might have been redefined earlier in the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you're right ;) . It's just that I never use T or F as variable in my code in order to avoid this kind of conflict

Answer (score 1):

looks like a regex may be a better fitting for your problem

```
str_extract_all(C, "\\w+ \\w+ \\[ID [0-9]+\\] \\[IC [0-9]+\\]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringr::str_split(C, "(?<=\\d\\])(?= \\w)")
```

Use look behind (https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the boundry.

EDIT: fixed as per @dc37's comments